# Conectar LDAP no symfony manual

Tags: php, symfony, openldap

Olá, estou tentando fazer um login com conexão ao LDAP, no symfony 1.4. Explodi as variáveis de conexão, ldap_connect e ldap_bind e elas me retornam True, porém eu não consigo redirecionar o usuário para dentro do meu sistema:

```
 if ($request->isMethod('post'))
{
    $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('signin'));

    $login = $request->getParameter('signin_username');
    $pass  = $request->getParameter('signin_password');
    $host = '192.168.1.xxx';
    $port = 389;

    $link = ldap_connect($host, $port);
    $bind = @ldap_bind($link, $login, $pass);

    if($link)
    {
        echo 'link ok ';
        if($bind){
            echo 'bind ok';
   //  $signinUrl = sfConfig::get('app_sf_guard_plugin_success_signin_url',  $user->getReferer($request->getReferer()));
   // return $this->redirect('' != $signinUrl ? $signinUrl : '@homepage');
       header('location:@homepage');

        }
        else{
            echo 'close ok';
            ldap_close($link);
        }
    }
```